# VB program to calculate monthly deposits plus interest

Tags: vb.net

I am having issues trying to make a calculator that accurately calculates deposits plus the amount of interest that is added monthly. I dont know how to incorporate a loop that can add monthly deposits to total deposits, then adds the total deposits plus total interest times the interest rate / 100 / 12 to the total deposits. Here is what I have so far. Sorry am super new to VB !

```
    Dim intMonthlyDeposit As Interger
    Dim intMonthsTotal As Integer
    Dim intAnnualRate As Interget
    Dim decTotalDeposits As Decimal
    Dim decTotalInterest As Decimal
    Dim decTotalTotal As Decimal

    Try
        intMonthlyDeposit = CInt(txtMonthlyDeposits.Text)
        intMonthsTotal = CInt(txtMonths.Text)
        decAnnualRate = CDec(txtAnnualRate.Text)
        decTotalDeposits = 0
        decTotalInterest = 0
        decTotalTotal = 0

        decTotalDeposits = decMonthlyDeposit * intMonthsTotal

        decTotalInterest = decTotalDeposits * (decAnnualRate / 100) 

        decTotalTotal = decTotalDeposits + decTotalInterest

        lblTotDeposit.Text = decTotalDeposits.ToString("C")

        lblTot.Text = decTotalTotal.ToString("C")

        lblTotInterest.Text = decTotalInterest.ToString("C")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Enter a Valid Number")

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: So why can't you just multiply your values by 12, for every month? You don't need a loop...

Comment: Thats exactly what I say but a loop is required for some odd reason. This is for a class.

Comment: maybe you should consider wrapping that code in a loop of months? Foe each month in year then use your code within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented the loop for calculating total interest and total deposits correctly.

For index As Integer = 1 To intMonthsTotal Step 1
                decTotalDeposits += decMonthlyDeposit
                decTotalInterest += (decTotalDeposits + decTotalInterest) * ((decAnnualRate / 100) / 12)